# In BackEnd developement is it better to store the image file in mysql database in form of URL or LongBlob?

Tags: mysql, node.js, postman

//This question doesn't require a code so please don't consider this

Comment: URL to file on disk is better for performance.

Answer (score 0):

best way to store image as url in mysql and upload image file in server folder.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe here isn't the best place to make that question.

I guess [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/164905/how-best-to-store-images-on-a-file-system) can be more helpful